# Proving that the interior of any other circle through two distinguished points must contain at least one point in between them on the original circle

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have two distinct distinguished points $x_1,x_2$ in the plane, and two different circles $C,C'$ that pass through both of them them. Let $y_1$ be a point strictly in between $x_1$ and $x_2$ on $C$ in the clockwise direction, and similarly let $y_2$ be a point in the counter-clockwise direction. Then is it true that either $y_1$ or $y_2$ must be in the interior disc of $C'$? This is a lemma that would prove correctness of a divide-and-conquer algorithm for Delaunay triangulations. Ideally my friend and I would like a simple elementrary proof, e.g. using the triangle inequality. But a simple proof using more advanced tools like calculus/real analysis would also be ok.

Answer (score 1):

First we show that distinct circles can intersect at at most two points.

Proof: Recall that any three points in the plane define a unique circle. Therefore, if two circles share three or more points then they are the same circle. Hence distinct circles can share at most two points.

Now onto your proof. If $C=C'$ then we are done. If $C\ne C'$ then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the only points of intersection between the circles. Hence at least one of the curves between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is completely contained in $C'$, proving your claim (since if neither were completely contained, we get more intersection points).

Comment: This is essentially along the lines of what I was originally thinking, but there is one sticky point. Basically you have to prove that it is impossible for BOTH curves to be strictly outside except at $x_1,x_2$. Intuitively this is obvious, but I don't know a clean way to prove it.

Comment: @user2566092 Use the fact that distinct circles can be tangent at at most one point. If both curves are outside (and $x_1\ne x_2$) then the circles would be tangent at $2$ points.

Comment: I agree but knowing that two distinct circles have at most one common tangent point, and knowing that if one curve is strictly outside the other curve except at two common points then they have both those points as common tangent points seems non-trivial without some somewhat advanced machinery.